# wxpython change text after function call

Tags: python, wxpython

On click of my "browse" button, the text in my textbox "tc1" does not change. I get a console error of "global name 'tc1' is not defined". I just want the text of tc1 to change when I click button1

python:

```
def InitUI(self):

  panel = wx.Panel(self)

  button1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Browse...")
  button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBrowse)

  tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "Text")

def OnBrowse(self, event):
  return tc1.SetValue("New Text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>you must declare it global</s>
This should be an attribute of the class

```
self.tc1 = None
def InitUI(self):
  button1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Browse...")
  button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBrowse)
  self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "Text")

def OnBrowse(self, event):
  return self.tc1.SetValue("New Text")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a class for the GUI and the `TextCtrl` is part of that GUI, so I think it makes sense to make `tc1` an attribute of `self`:

```
def InitUI(self):
  ...    
  self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "Text")

def OnBrowse(self, event):
  return self.tc1.SetValue("New Text")
```

Comment: very good point through my sleep deprived eyes i did not notice the self when i looked at it this morning and I thought they were just functions...